# ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed Bundling Python( pyQt + cx_Oracle) application using pyinstaller for Windows

Tags: python, oracle, pyqt5, pyinstaller, cx-oracle

I'm building a GUI application on Windows using pyQt which queries an Oracle database using a connection string such as `username/password@host_ip:port/db_name`. Now when I run the application using `python3 gui.py`, it works, connects to the host and extracts the required information but when I compile it to an exe, it gives me the infamous `ORA-12638`.

I've scoured the interwebs for solutions ie: how to properly package cx_Oracle applications using pyinstaller and have done the following:

1. Add InstantClient and Qt DLLs to the path
2. Create a `tnsnames.ora` in the same folder as the exe

But to no avail. The program works perfectly when I run it using `python3 gui.py` but somehow breaks when compiled. Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Question also asked here: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/328

Comment: When asking a question, please do not cross-post it elsewhere at the same time by default. When you do this, you are saying in each location that you do not care to be part of the community in each case - just that you are willing to spam to as many places as you can in order to get your answer. It is better to start off with one, and then if you do not get an answer within a day or so, post elsewhere.

Comment: Critically, if you do need to post elsewhere, please link each copy of the post to every other copy. This allows people helping you to check if it has already been answered, thus saving their time. When you do not cross-link between copies, it signals to readers that you do not mind wasting the time of volunteers.

Comment: If you do get an answer in one location, make sure you add a self-answer in every other location. This will ensure that if one copy is deleted, the useful information will be preserved in the other places the question was duplicated. Thank you.

Comment: I apologize for this. It was a time sensitive problem and I will answer it if I can find a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my issue by changing the contents of the `sqlnet.ora` file to

`SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)`

instead of

`SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)`

The corresponding issue I opened : https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/328